# Why is parallel implementation slower than serial? (Python multiprocessing module)

Tags: python, parallel-processing, scikit-learn, multiprocessing

I am trying to extend the scikit-learn class `KNeighborsClassifier` by introducing an alternative method of computing distances between neighbours (see [here](http://vene.ro/blog/word-movers-distance-in-python.html) if interested).

The parallelization scheme is the following:
given that we want to calculate distances between all elements of set A and set B, for each element in A (taken *sequentially* one after the other), calculate distances to all elements in B *in parallel*.
The time-consuming operation is calculating the distance between any two elements, so each process should carry out this fundamental operation.

The problem is that parallel execution is much slower than serial execution (using Python's `multiprocessing` module), both when using synchronous as well as asynchronous calls, regardless of the machine and the numbers of cores used.

I suspect that this is related to using shared variables, which are communicated in the background. The question is, which variables are being communicated and how could this be avoided?

Code:

```
class WordMoversKNN(KNeighborsClassifier):
"""K nearest neighbors classifier using the Word Mover's Distance.
Parameters
----------

W_embed : array, shape: (vocab_size, embed_size)
    Precomputed word embeddings between vocabulary items.
    Row indices should correspond to the columns in the bag-of-words input.
n_neighbors : int
    Number of neighbors to use by default for :meth:`k_neighbors` queries.
n_jobs : int
    The number of parallel jobs to run for Word Mover's Distance computation.
    If ``-1``, then the number of jobs is set to the number of CPU cores.
verbose : int, optional
    Controls the verbosity; the higher, the more messages. Defaults to 0.

"""

def __init__(self, W_embed, n_neighbors=1, n_jobs=1, verbose=5):
    self.W_embed = W_embed
    self.verbose = verbose
    if n_jobs == -1:
        n_jobs = mp.cpu_count()

    super(WordMoversKNN, self).__init__(n_neighbors=n_neighbors, n_jobs=n_jobs, metric='precomputed', algorithm='brute')

def _wmd(self, i, row, X_train):
    """Compute the WMD between training sample i and given test row.

    Assumes that `row` and train samples are sparse BOW vectors summing to 1.
    """
    union_idx = np.union1d(X_train[i].indices, row.indices)
    W_minimal = self.W_embed[union_idx]
    W_dist = euclidean_distances(W_minimal)
    bow_i = X_train[i, union_idx].A.ravel()
    bow_j = row[:, union_idx].A.ravel()
    return emd(bow_i, bow_j, W_dist)

def _wmd_row(self, row, X_train):
    """Wrapper to compute the WMD of a row with all training samples.

    Assumes that `row` and train samples are sparse BOW vectors summing to 1.
    Useful for parallelization.
    """
    n_samples_train = X_train.shape[0]
    return [self._wmd(i, row, X_train) for i in range(n_samples_train)]

def _pairwise_wmd(self, X_test, X_train=None, ordered=True):
    """Computes the word mover's distance between all train and test points.

    Parallelized over rows of X_test.

    Assumes that train and test samples are sparse BOW vectors summing to 1.

    Parameters
    ----------
    X_test: scipy.sparse matrix, shape: (n_test_samples, vocab_size)
        Test samples.

    X_train: scipy.sparse matrix, shape: (n_train_samples, vocab_size)
        Training samples. If `None`, uses the samples the estimator was fit with.
    ordered: returns result keeping the order of the rows in dist (following X_test).
        Otherwise, the rows of dist follow a potentially random order which does not follow the order
        of indices in X_test. However, computation is faster in this case (asynchronous parallel execution)

    Returns
    -------
    dist : array, shape: (n_test_samples, n_train_samples)
        Distances between all test samples and all train samples.

    """
    n_samples_test = X_test.shape[0]

    if X_train is None: X_train = self._fit_X

    if (self.n_jobs == 1) or (n_samples_test < 2*self.n_jobs):  # to avoid parallelism overhead for small test samples
        dist = [ self._wmd_row( test_sample , X_train ) for test_sample in X_test ]
    else:
        if self.verbose:
            print("WordMoversKNN set to use {} parallel processes".format(self.n_jobs))
        if ordered:
            dist = Parallel(n_jobs=self.n_jobs, verbose=self.verbose)( delayed(self._wmd_row) (test_sample, X_train) for test_sample in X_test)
        else: # Asynchronous call is faster but returns results in random order              
            pool = mp.Pool(processes=self.n_jobs)

            results = [pool.apply_async(self._wmd_row, args=(test_sample, X_train)) for test_sample in X_test]
            dist = [p.get() for p in results]
    return np.array(dist)


def calculate(self, X):
    """Predict the class labels for the provided data
    Parameters
    ----------
    X : scipy.sparse matrix, shape (n_test_samples, vocab_size)
        Test samples.
    Returns
    -------
    y : array of shape [n_samples]
        Class labels for each data sample.
    """
    X = check_array(X, accept_sparse='csr', copy=True)
    X = normalize(X, norm='l1', copy=False)
    dist = self._pairwise_wmd(X)
    # A matrix of distances given to predict in combination with metric = 'precomputed'
    # means that no more distance calculations take place. Neighbors are found simply by sorting
    return super(WordMoversKNN, self).predict(dist)
```

Comment: Parallel can actually be slower then serial in case when there is e.g. only one processor (e.g. single core CPU) and so the operation can't process in parallel. In parallel there will be small amount of time needed to switch the context and this time(s) will not be needed when processed serial.

Comment: @dee Thanks. The thing is that I have tried running the same code on several (multi-core) machines and using a different number of cores, but execution is always much slower. At the same time, when I try the same module (`multiprocessing`) for some toy examples (e.g. sorting arrays or applying some mathematical function over a list of arrays) I can see a speed-up.

Comment: `multiprocessing` can also be slower than serial execution if the IPC costs (meaning copying `test_sample` and `X_train` to the children processes, and copying the list returned from `_wmd_row` back to the parent) are very high. IPC is pretty slow, so for very large objects it can outweigh the gains you get from parallelizing your computations. If you have a huge list where you need to do a bunch of not-very-expensive calculations, `multiprocessing` may not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem was that *for each row* of matrix `X_test` a new process was spawned, each time requiring passing the full `X_train` as well as other variables (e.g. `self.X_embed`) for every process. Pickling and dispatching these variables is very time consuming, because of their size.
I got a tremendous speed-up when I split the matrix `X_test` in `n_jobs` chunks of size `X_test.shape[0]//n_jobs`, overall spawning only `n_jobs` processes and having to pass the variables `n_jobs` times instead of `X_test.shape[0]` times.
However, because of the size of the variables that have to be communicated, I believe that for this type of problem, data parallelism is a much more appropriate approach than task parallelism, and I therefore intend to use `mpi4py`, so that each process separately creates its own `self.W_embed`, `X_train` and `X_test` matrices, communicating only the results of the computation.